# Error al convertir decimal de textBox c# a decimal SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenas tengo un texbox mediante el cual actualizo un campo de la base de datos, en el texBox solo dejo seleccionar números y un caracter '.' o ',' mediante un key press:

```
  if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
         || e.KeyChar == '.' ) //aqui es donde pruebo con . o con , 
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
          
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

El tema esta en que cuando lanzo la query:

```
 int idF = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion); //conexion
            string query = @"UPDATE filtro1 SET particulas =  '" + decimal.Parse(tbUpdateParticulas.Text.Trim()) + "' where id = " + idF; //query parseando a decimal el contenido del texBox
            cn.Open(); //abro conexión 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn); 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//ejecuto el comando
            cn.Close(); //cierro
```

Si el caracter keyChar que tengo es la coma salta la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si tengo un . en el evento keyPress se actualiza la base de datos ignorandolo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da igual que parsee con float, decimal, double.. hace lo mismo en las mismas circunstancias. Otra cosa rara es que el error dice al convertir a numeric pero el campo en SQLServer es decimal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo parsearlo correctamente y actualizar la base de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es entender lo que estás haciendo. En realidad no estás insertando un `double`, lo que estas haciendo es insertar un `string` (concatenando un `string` en la sentencia sql). En este caso, el string no puede tener comas, debe tener un punto como separador de decimales.

```
string query = @"UPDATE filtro1 SET particulas =  '" + tbUpdateParticulas.Text.Trim().Replace(",", ".") + "' where id = " + idF;
```

Aunque la forma correcta de hacerlo es parametrizar la consulta, en concreto con el objeto `SqlCommand`. Pero una vez más asegúrate que `tbUpdateParticulas.Text.Trim()` contiene un `Double`.

```
string query = @"UPDATE filtro1 SET particulas =  @Valor where id = @idF"; //query parseando a decimal el contenido del texBox
cn.Open(); //abro conexión 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn); 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idF", SqlDbType.Int); //Añadimos un parámetro
command.Parameters("@idF").Value = idF; //Ponemos el valor al parámetro
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Valor", SqlDbType.Double); //Otro parámetro
command.Parameters("@Valor").Value = decimal.Parse(tbUpdateParticulas.Text.Trim()); //valor parámetro
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//ejecuto el comando
```

Comment: Gracias Roger funcionó, pero el string solo me lo parsea con una coma, con un punto no lo detecta y lo inserta en la base de datos sin decimal

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba que `collation` (intercalación) tienes para esa tabla. Puedes hacerlo lanzando la siguiente query :

```
select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Your DB Name','collation')
```

Windows y .NET utilizan la `collation Little Indian`. A ver si para esa tabla puedes tener otra diferente y no te está cogiendo el punto (.) como una coma(').

Comment: efectivamente esta en Modern_Spanish_CI_AS, gracias.

Comment: Ese puede ser el problema de que no te coja los decimales con separador punt (.)